# Enable login to Linux machine using picture password

Tags: login, password

Is there any program to enable login to a Linux machine using picture password like in Windows 8? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

currently I think there is no official application but you can do it from google package https://code.google.com/p/pam-face-authentication/wiki/WikiInstallationFromSource

Installation:
open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake qt4-qmake libqt4-dev libx11-dev libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev libpam0g-dev checkinstall 

cd /tmp && wget http://pam-face-authentication.googlecode.com/files/pam-face-authentication-0.3.tar.gz
tar zxf pam-face-authentication-0.3.tar.gz && cd pam-face-authentication-*
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=pam-authentication-face-auth
```

Check the above link for more information about installation and configuration .

Comment: How to start this app it is not showing in the menu

Comment: have you studied the link carefully ?

Comment: i did but it is not starting